# "Much of it is" or "Much of it are"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I'm writing an college-entrance essay and for me it's imperative that I understand and implement the correct one of these two expressions:

> "Much of it is" or "Much of it are"

If you need context:

> I'm having trouble with my writing. The reason I'm having trouble is that much of it **is** about....

Should there be an "is" or an "are"?

Comment: How to remember: *Much* divides stuff into just two parts and talks about just one part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Much of it is"** is the correct grammar. Much always applies to singular nouns (i.e. quantifying a noun that is a singular entity). In addition, "it" is a singular pronoun. So it is without question that "is" is the correct verb conjugation to use.

Were it plural, it would be "many of them are".

Comment: @David as an aside, good luck!